# Creating a text file with PHP?

Tags: php, text, fopen, fwrite, chmod

I'm trying to use PHP to create a text file, but I keep getting the "can't open file" error. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
chmod('text.txt', 0777);

$textFile = "text.txt";
$fileHandle = fopen($textFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Hello!";
fwrite($fileHandle, $stringData);
fclose($fileHandle);
```

Comment: Is the text file in the same directory ?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not going to be able to `chmod()` a file that doesn't exists. You must have write privileges on the parent folder in order to allow `Apache` (if your running Apache, otherwise whichever user your allowing to write the file) as a user to write inside of that folder (whether it is the root, or a sub folder).

Additionally, you should do some error handling on your file writing:

```
<?php
if($fh = fopen('text.txt','w')){
    $stringData = "Hello!";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData,1024);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! But how would I go about adding write privileges on the parent folder? (I'm a bit in over my head here, even a link to send me in the right direction would help.)

Comment: you need some sort of FTP access. most programs (like filezilla,winscp,dreamweaver), allow you to right click on the folder and set the users and permission levels.